# "gunicorn/finish 127. exec: gunicorn: not found" when updating local azure ml deployment in docker

Tags: azure, machine-learning, gunicorn, endpoint

Yesterday I was following along a tutorial provided by Azure in deploying machine learning models to endpoints:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-online-endpoints?tabs=azure-cli

In this tutorial I ended up successfully deploying a simple linear regression model to a local endpoint with a docker container. However any time I try to update the deployment (i.e. by adding a simple python package dependency in the conda yaml file) and subsequently running:

```
az ml online-deployment update --local -n blue --endpoint $ENDPOINT_NAME -f endpoints/online/managed/sample/blue-deployment.yml
```

The container containing model goes into a failed state and logs that exec: gunicorn cannot be found. Using the same command as above works fine for updating the deployment that is actually deployed to azure online (with removing --local). However I would like to develop locally, and redeploying my container for each time my environment changes feels silly. For context the relevant yaml files are provided below, strangely enough in the tutorial I do not touch a docker file. Any thoughts or comments on how to proceed are appreciated!

**blue-deployment.yml**

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/managedOnlineDeployment.schema.json
name: blue
endpoint_name: my-endpoint
model:
  path: ../../model-1/model/
code_configuration:
  code: ../../model-1/onlinescoring/
  scoring_script: score.py
environment: 
  conda_file: ../../model-1/environment/conda.yml
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04:latest
instance_type: Standard_DS2_v2
instance_count: 1
```

**conda.yml**

```yaml
name: model-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - numpy=1.21.2
  - pip=21.2.4
  - scikit-learn=0.24.2
  - scipy=1.7.1
  - pyodbc=4.0.34
  - pip:
    - azureml-defaults==1.47.0
    - inference-schema[numpy-support]==1.5
    - joblib==1.0.1
```

**endpoint.yml**

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/managedOnlineEndpoint.schema.json
name: my-endpoint
auth_mode: key
```

I tried to update an existing local docker container that contained a sklearn regression model which was originally deployed through Azure cli. I expected the containers environment to be updated with a new dependency such that I could use newly added python packages in my code. However, the container goes into a failed state and cannot be restarted as it fails to find gunicorn. I also tried adding gunicorn as a dependency in the conda.yml but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, make sure to make your question as short as possible removing non-tech phrases. It's raise readability.

Comment: When you add gunicorn to your conda dependancy, do the logs change? For me adding that and then a bunch of other libraries in the conda env solved the problem.